# Decrypting PHPass Wordpress Hashes w/o Access to Original Site

Tags: php, wordpress, encryption

The question straight up, more explanation down below - **is there a reasonably appropriate way to decrypt a somewhat recently updated Wordpress password hash, even if it may take a while to decode?**

We currently have a full database backup from a while back that we have free reign to work with if need be, I'm just not sure of the starting point. We have hashcat available but I'm not sure what variables exactly should be used. We're okay to run a crack for an extended period of time if need be. I know MD5 was cracked a while back so I'm wondering if the new phpass is crackable if we have all database information available. Would greatly appreciate any insight or perhaps a pointer to the appropriate direction or resource that we can look into.

Comment: The point of proper password hashing is that you can't crack it.  You understand that right?  Tell the company to cut their losses and move on.

Comment: Well, MD5 was considered a strong hash function there for a while before it was cracked. This isn't something I've followed so I'm wondering if it's possible. I'm coming at this assuming this is a loss tbh, but want to help if at all possible.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no way for you to retrieve those passwords.  Not in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: If there's no such thing as a "reset password" feature available to them, then you'll have to wait until you can verify it all and get the host to reset the passwords. Those passwords aren't "decrypt-able" - or else there'd be very little reason to hash them in the first place..

Comment: Alright, I hear you. Thanks.

Comment: "Apparently though, there's a backdoor, as someone has gained access to the system already" -- this assumes that the old site password was not "1234" before it was hacked.  The web developer not sharing access to a customer's site with the customer is not the sign of a good developer.

Comment: Do you have access to phpMyAdmin or similiar on the server?

Comment: Unfortunately no, like I said the deceased was the only one with credentials for both the hosting environment and the wordpress installation. Otherwise, I'd be able to change the pass without a problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 1) It describes a situation that does not feature any code and 2) Is highly suspect and dubious (or simply ficticious) in the way that various sub-topics of the question are outlined.

Comment: All that comes to mind is that any sensible hosting provider would investigate on and remove any such malicious situation on their servers, with or without the user's intervention or consent.

Comment: If you have access to the full site - including the SQL tables - you don't need to break any password, as you can simply change it. It's how I got access to the Wordpress site at my job when I first came in. If you don't have access to the SQL tables AND there's no 'reset password option', you should be able to get the hosting company to park the domain, especially if it's linking to porn, which is against many if not most hosting providers' terms of service. Also, I second what Martin said: this is highly suspect.

Comment: I've flagged the question to close as well, Martin, wouldn't let me delete it.  And Martin, just telling it how I see it here. I'm not familiar with server environments or the general processes short of enough understanding to get a Wordpress site up and rolling smoothly, I'm a graphic designer in the process of learning web development for pete's sake. FatCow said they couldn't do anything until proof of ownership was provided, when submitted they said 3-4 weeks.  I did not know about the DNS authorities submission though, thank you for that. That will be the next course of action.

Comment: If you're a graphic designer, then `a)` why did they ask you to solve their server level issue and `b)` why did you seemingly accept this task? If they need proof of ownership then the Executor or Attourney acting for the deceased needs to sort this out. It's not your issue, and it's not StackOverflows issue. Cracking passwords is ***not*** the way to resolve this.

Comment: Because A, when you live in a small town if you can fix a computer anybody with a tech-based problem comes to you, and B, I didn't. I said I'd see if I can contact the host and they mentioned that they had a few files on hand, but nothing with a full backup. I took it as a challenge but didn't promise anything. Interested in learning and helping people out if I can, my dude. All that being said I now know that it's more or less impossible to crack/fix, so the question was answered in a sense. Thus why I'm trying to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the database and you know it is a WordPress website, you can SAFELY create a new wordpress install, the same version as the one you are currently running, create an account with a known password, and copy those database fields into the current running DB. Then, simply, login using those hashed credentials and admin privileges and make your appropriate changes.

WILD GUESS, but stackoverflow will not decrypt PHP's password hash for you and post it here.

Comment: Didn't think of that, will give that a shot. Should at least get us part way to getting the site back up. Thanks!

Comment: @IkeDoud just make sure to make backups of the Database and any other changes before trying things out. The situation sounds bad, but it can always be worse.

Answer (score 1):

> I know MD5 was cracked a while back so I'm wondering if the new phpass is crackable if we have all database information available.

This is incorrect. `MD5` has not been "cracked", but it can now be processed so fast that a solution value (or duplicate) can be found relaively very quickly. This is not the same as a "*crack*" which is a mathematical reversal of the process used to create the cyphertext/hash.

Because `MD5` can be processed so quickly now, and because it always produces the same outcome from the same input, there are things called "rainbow tables" which store the plaintext and the md5 hash by association so make it easy to enter one, and find out the other. [See more here](http://project-rainbowcrack.com/table.htm).

---

> That said, to explain: We've got a very strange situation on our hands. I was recently approached by a business who assumed that web developer also meant white hat, apparently. Long story short, the only person with access to this company's website passed away in a car crash three months ago. Server access, wordpress access, the whole nine yards - he was the only one with access, and he left zero notes. The business hasn't done anything with the website since then, but apparently last week the site was exploited and is now forwarding to a porn site, which is murdering their reputation currently. We've contacted the hosts and they can't do anything because we don't currently have the deceased verification information... So we're stuck. We've contacted the hosts management and have submitted the appropriate documents but they said it could take 3-4 weeks for a response. So there's that.

This sounds like utter rubbish.

There are various points on here that sound extremely dubious. No server is accessible to only one person, unless it's their own PC sitting in their living room or garage, etc., a properly maintained and managed system (as this appears to be by reference to hosting companies, etc.) will have access at a root level (and probably lower levels) available to the Hosting administration. Typically there are 5-6 access levels between the website developer and the chef honcho all of whom can if needbe access most parts of an end users account.

People die all the time. This is no reason to sink a server account just because someone passed away. Send legal documentation from a legal professional to the Hosting company explaining and showing that the account holder has expired and requesting the account be transferred.

This may take time depending on the size of the company and if the business is willing to pay for this work to be carried out.

If you have issues with the server hosts then you can also apply to the DNS authorities/company to have the domain name removed and redirected to another account with another host. This will be virtually seemless for the web domain visitors.

I repeat, various aspects of this question as described sound at best dubious and at worst simply ficticious.